# try_lock_for not working as intended

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, mutex

I was fiddling around with some code in c++ that for some reason didn't want to work and i narrowed it down to this case:

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test()
{
  timed_mutex m;
  m.lock();
  std::cout << "Can i have the lock? " << m.try_lock() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "in test(), should block for 10 seconds" << std::endl;
  bool got_lock = m.try_lock_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
  std::cout << "Now i've blocked, got the lock: " << got_lock << std::endl;
  m.unlock();
}

int main()
{
  thread t = thread(&test);
  t.join();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem is that test() doesn't block at all, even though the `try_lock` returns false. Is there something i have overlooked or is this a bug in gcc or where should i go next to find out what's wrong? Thankful for any advice and help!

I compiled this little program like so: `g++ -pthread -std=c++11 threads.cpp -o threads`
and if it's any help this is the version of gcc and my os:

```
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

uname -a
Linux *computername* 3.6.11-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Dec 18 08:57:15 CET 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: `real    0m10.003s` That's my runtime when running your code with g++ 4.6.3. Seems ok.

Comment: Also works fine here using g++ 4.7.2 on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Anton your code fails on try_lock_for() ?

Comment: @billz It seems so at least, it always finishes almost instantly, ie, no block is seen for me.

Comment: 3 of us tested your code and it worked as expected.

Comment: Yeah, i don't really know where to go from here, anyone able to test on archlinux perhaps? I think i'll have to go make a post there.

Comment: I can reproduce the behavior on archlinux (same gcc, mainline 3.7 kernel): `real 0m0.004s`. This might be related to the particular gcc version.

Comment: @AlexandreC. Ok, thanks for trying it out! How should i go from here? Do i file a bug report in the archlinux bugtracker?

Comment: @Anton: this may not be related to archlinux at all, but perhaps to some undefined behaviour in your code, or a gcc bug, or a pthreads bug, or anything. I'd suggest trying this on another box with gcc 4.7.2, and ask the gcc mailing list what they think of your little test case if the behavior is incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code's behavior is undefined. `std::timed_mutex` has *non-recursive ownership* semantics.
It's forbidden to acquire the lock (include try_lock family) second time on the *same* thread.

C++11 Standard 30.4.1.3.1 [thread.timedmutex.class]/p3/b2: (thanks to Howard Hinnant)

> 3 The behavior of a program is undefined if:
>
> - a thread that owns a `timed_mutex` object calls `lock()`, `try_lock()`, `try_lock_for()`, or `try_lock_until()` on that object, or

<del>C++11 Standard 30.4.1.2 [thread.mutex.requirements.mutex]/p6-7:</del>

---

**EDITED:**

> how i am going to "work around this" or get it to behave the way i want? Should i use a recursive mutex instead?

Generally speaking, it's discouraged to acquire/release lock of mutex object in light of exception safty. If you use `unique_lock` object instead, `owns_lock()` member function may help you.
Meanwhile recursive-mutex is useless for your purpose, because "recursive" means only "I(a thread) can acquire lock twice or more when I already own lock."

```
void test()
{
  std::timed_mutex m;
  std::unique_lock<decltype(m)> lk(m, std::defer_lock);

  // acquire lock
  lk.lock();
  // You can query locked status via unique_lock object
  std::cout << "Do I have own lock? " << lk.owns_lock() << std::endl;
  // release lock
  lk.unlock();
}
```

Comment: +1 Right answer wrong quote.  30.4.1.3.1 [thread.timedmutex.class]/p3/b2: a thread that owns a `timed_mutex` object calls `lock()`, `try_lock()`, `try_lock_for()`, or `try_lock_until()` on that object,

Comment: In that case i think i have another question, namely as to how i am going to "work around this" or get it to behave the way i want, should i post another question about that or edit this question to include it? Should i use a recursive mutex instead?